# jdbc wont connect with java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I downloaded the latest version of mysql connector "mysql-connector-java-8.0.11"
and I tried to connect it with java using netbeans but it won't work
also, I added the jar file in my project lib but nothing happened
it gives me this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 com.mysql.jdbc.cj.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at learnjdbc.Learnjdbc.main(Learnjdbc.java:18)
```

this is my code

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Learnjdbc {

public static String name="root";
public static String password="ismail19972018";
public static String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/myinfo";
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection connect=null;
    Statement stm=null;
    PreparedStatement prstm=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;


    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.cj.Driver");
        connect=DriverManager.getConnection(url,name,password);
        System.out.println("connected");

    }catch(SQLException ex){



           ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [tag:mysql-error-1064] has exactly nothing to do with it, or any other MySQL error code. MySQL hasn't even executed yet. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: Either you don't have the MySQL Connector/J driver on the classpath, or you still have MySQL Connector/J 5.1.x or earlier (which doesn't have `com.mysql.jdbc.cj.Driver`, but `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the class that implements `java.sql.Driver` in MySQL Connector/J is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. The class name in the code `com.mysql.jdbc.cj.Driver` does not exists which causes the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot connect

This is not 'cannot connect', it is 'cannot find class', and the `Class.forName()` line has been unnecessary since 2007.

Just remove it.